# Build nested JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I would like to replicate this example data set into nested JSON using JavaScript or Angularjs or any javascript library.

Data:

```
PrimaryId,FirstName,LastName,City,CarName,DogName
100,John,Smith,NewYork,Toyota,Spike
100,John,Smith,NewYork,BMW,Spike
100,John,Smith,NewYork,Toyota,Rusty
100,John,Smith,NewYork,BMW,Rusty
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Volkswagen,Buddy
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Ford,Buddy
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Audi,Buddy
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Volkswagen,Max
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Ford,Max
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Audi,Max
102,Julia,Brown,London,Mini,Lucy
```

Javascript:

```
var file = reader.result; 
var singleRow = readerFile.split(/\r\n|\n/);
var header = singleRow[0].split(',');
var result =[];  

    for ( var i=1; i < file.length; i++ ){                                      
        var elementData = singleRow[i].split(',');                              
        elementData = elementData.filter(function(n){ return n != "" });        
        var Obj = {};                                                           

        for ( var j=0; j < header.length; j++ ){
            Obj[header[j]] = elementData[j];
            /*
              - How can i build child object and append back to Obj before j loop
              - How can i build multiple child for same parent 
            */                  
        }
        result.push(Obj);                                                       
    }
    console.log(" Print the JSON Object : " + JSON.stringify(result));
```

Desired Output:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "City": "NewYork", 
            "FirstName": "John", 
            "PrimaryId": 100, 
            "LastName": "Smith", 
            "CarName": [
                "Toyota", 
                "BMW"
            ], 
            "DogName": [
                "Spike", 
                "Rusty"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "City": "Sydney", 
            "FirstName": "Ben", 
            "PrimaryId": 101, 
            "LastName": "Swan", 
            "CarName": [
                "Volkswagen", 
                "Ford", 
                "Audi"
            ], 
            "DogName": [
                "Buddy", 
                "Max"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "City": "London", 
            "FirstName": "Julia", 
            "PrimaryId": 102, 
            "LastName": "Brown", 
            "CarName": [
                "Mini"
            ], 
            "DogName": [
                "Lucy"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If Firstname, Lastname and City has same values then CarName and DogName values should be child object under the same parent

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON object".](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) Anyway, is it just the `PrimaryId` field that should be used for grouping the data? That is, is it safe to assume that a given ID will always have the same first and last names and city, or could those fields also potentially end up as arrays within a given ID? A completely generic solution would need to allow for any of the fields repeating, but if it is only two specific fields and the field names are always the same then less generic code will likely be simpler.

Comment: I don't know the right and detailed answer, but I think you should look in the hashmap or hashtable data structure, where an object with a specific key can only occur one. Just go through all the rows and search for the id, if not exist, then make a new one. Then update or add all the other fields depending on if it is an single or multi value.

Comment: @nnnnnn thank you and i corrected my question. yes we can assume 3 column entries will be same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reformatted your initial code a little bit, but it doesn't change the initial logic. One key observation is that even if the `FirstName`, `LastName` and `City` are the same, that may not be a unique person, hence you should use the `PrimaryId` instead, to determine uniqueness.

Look at the post-processing section for the new code:

```
const data = `PrimaryId,FirstName,LastName,City,CarName,DogName
100,John,Smith,NewYork,Toyota,Spike
100,John,Smith,NewYork,BMW,Spike
100,John,Smith,NewYork,Toyota,Rusty
100,John,Smith,NewYork,BMW,Rusty
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Volkswagen,Buddy
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Ford,Buddy
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Audi,Buddy
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Volkswagen,Max
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Ford,Max
101,Ben,Swan,Sydney,Audi,Max
102,Julia,Brown,London,Mini,Lucy`;

var singleRow = data.split(/\r\n|\n/);
var header = singleRow[0].split(',');
var result =[];

for (var i = 1; i < singleRow.length; i++) {
  var elementData = singleRow[i].split(',');
  elementData = elementData.filter(function(n) { return n != '' });
  var Obj = {};
  for ( var j=0; j < header.length; j++ ){
    Obj[header[j]] = elementData[j];
  }
  result.push(Obj);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));


// Post-processing code starts here
const people = {};

// Create a map of unique people first
result.forEach(function (object) {
  if (!people[object.PrimaryId]) {
    people[object.PrimaryId] = {
      City: object.City,
      FirstName: object.FirstName,
      PrimaryId: object.PrimaryId,
      LastName: object.LastName,
      CarName: [],
      DogName: [],
    };
  }
  // As you iterate through your results, if this person already exists
  // add to their array of car and dogs.
  people[object.PrimaryId].CarName.push(object.CarName);
  people[object.PrimaryId].DogName.push(object.DogName);
});

// Convert back into an array
const peopleList = [];
Object.keys(people).forEach(function (primaryId) {
  peopleList.push(people[primaryId]);
})

console.log(peopleList);
```

Comment: thanks man, How would you build object of CarName instead of just appending the value ? for example`  CarName: [
                "type1":"Volkswagen", 
                "type2:"Ford", 
                "type3":"Audi"
            ] `

Answer (score 3):

First of all, since you already know the property names, there's no point in parsing the first row.

I would do something like this:

```
let results = {};
for (let i = 1; i < file.length; i++) {
  let entry = getEntry(results, file[i][0]);
  entry.DogName.push(file[i][DOGNAME_INDEX]);
  entry.CarName.push(file[i][CARNAME_INDEX]);
  entry.LastName = file[i][LASTNAME_INDEX];
  ...
}

// and now to convert this into an array
let array = Object.keys(results).map(key => results[key]);


// retrieves or creates an entry for a given primary key
function getEntry(results, id) {
  return results[id] || (results[id] = {});
}
```

You could also get fancier and dynamically determine what the column indexes are, but the way I have it just keeps things simple.

Answer (score 3):

Made a fiddle for you, it gives the desired output with some things in a different order than you presented.

You can save the indexes of the headers:

```
var Index = {};
for(var k = 0; k < header.length; k++)
{
    Index[header[k]] = k;
}
```

And keep a list of cities:

```
var cities = [];
....
cities.push(data[Index["City"]]);
```

To use for later so that you don't keep making more objects if the city already exists:

```
obj = result.data[cities.indexOf(data[Index["City"]])];
```

The JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3u28aon3/1/